# SQL get rid of extra spaces

Tags: sql

I have some data here that goes like this:

```
'US     ' -- (5 spaces)
```

and I have over 300 records like this, is there a way to get rid of those 5 spaces?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` to remove trailing or leading spaces.

If you're just selecting the record:

```
SELECT RTRIM(State) AS State
FROM YourTable
```

If you want to update the table to remove the spaces:

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET State = RTRIM(State)
```

Comment: so with `update yourtable set State = RTRIM(State)` it will take out the extra spaces and update it with whats already there minus the spaces?

Comment: Correct. In your example, it basically translates to `UPDATE YourTable SET State = RTRIM('US ')` which becomes `UPDATE YourTable SET State = 'US'`  If you have multiple records, each one will be updated with a version that is `RTRIM`ed.

Comment: Say if I have one record that says `'US     '` and another record `'Canada'` will it shink down the other record? I am hoping it does not

Comment: I can't tell from the formatting whether `'Canada'` has any spaces at the end or not, but `RTRIM` will remove all trailing spaces, period. It won't remove any other characters, just trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support an RTRIM() or TRIM() function.

You can also replace the spaces with empty strings:

```
select replace('abcde   ', ' ', '')
```

(The replace function may be called something different in different databases.)

Another possibility is that the underlying type is CHAR rather than VARCHAR.  In your example, the column might be declared as `char(7)` rather than `varchar(7)`.  If that is the case, then you cannot remove the spaces, because the value is padded out to seven characters.

The best thing to do in this case is to change the definition to varchar(7).

Comment: 'some  random  text' would become 'somerandomtext'

Answer (score 0):

Use `RTRIM` to remove any trailing blanks after a string.

SELECT RTRIM(col1) FROM tbl1

Additionally, you can use `LTRIM` to remove any leading blanks.

To my knowledge, this function works in SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL and PL/SQL.